How to evaluate the performance of a class based on a binary target while removing the effect of other dependent features?
Here is the problem i'm facing:
I have a dataset of maintenance performed with two categorical variables (or more) (e.g. supplier and customer). Each have hundreds of different classes. These features are dependent on each others (one customer may prefers some suppliers for convenience or skill requirements). For each maintenance, I have a known binary target (0 bad, 1 good).
I want to be able to evaluate the performance of, for example, a given supplier based on the target while removing the effect of the other feature(s) (customer).
As an extreme example case: if a customer break its asset every day, the supplier repairing it will have a very low score (all target to 0) but due to the customer and not the supplier. I imagine there is a way to use the distribution for this particular customer with other suppliers to mitigate the result on the evaluated supplier.
My goal here is not to have a predictive model but rather a way to describe the dataset as describe above.
Details about the dataset:

About 5.000 unique (supplier, customer) tuples
Available rows per tuples go from 1 to 1000 (can remove lower end as needed)
50.000 rows

I've tried some metrics like Cramer's V statistic or weight of evidence on on-hot-encoded features, it gives some insights but does not eliminate the dependency.
A random tree classifier model gave me interesting results in the first 2 or 3 nodes but it is quickly limited by over fitting. It also gives answer only for few classes and not a metric for each.
I've also read this post on random and fixed effects but as i understand it's not really what I search for.
Do you have any suggestion on metrics or methods I could use ?
I'm quite new to data analysis, do not hesitate to correct me on the terms.
Note: i'm using Python if this is relevant

Based on the "Details about the dataset, you have only two variables - supplier ID and customer ID. Is that right ? If not then please provide more details.

In the full dataset I will have more variables (like: building site, asset type, components, etc.) but starting with a simple case with only 2 variables (supplier ID and customer ID) may be sufficient, it will be easier to understand the underlying concept and it reduce the number of unique tuples in each cross-categories. Therefore, if you have a solution or explanation for 2 variables it's already helping, if you have a solution for n categorical variables it can help too, if the solutions are fundamentally different, I would be interested to understand why.
